# Getting GC overhead limit exceeded with Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table tableA which is partitioned on adv_id and dt

```
col_name       data_type
adv_id         int 
url            string
dt             int
```

I am firing a query.

```
SELECT adv_id, url FROM tableA
WHERE 
dt = '20200510' 
AND adv_id IN (5039) limit 100;
```

Why do i get a GC overhead limit exceeded error and how do I fix this?
Note that using `adv_id = 5039` works here. But i need to check for multiple values and hence the IN clause.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter.toString(SingleByteCharsetConverter.java:335)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getString(ResultSetRow.java:819)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getString(ByteArrayRow.java:70)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5816)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5693)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.datastore.CharRDBMSMapping.getObject(CharRDBMSMapping.java:473)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.SingleFieldMapping.getObject(SingleFieldMapping.java:220)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.getObject(ResultClassROF.java:267)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.nextResultSetElement(ForwardQueryResult.java:181)
    at
```

Comment: this is because you are exceeding the limit of memory running the MR job. how much memory are you handling in your Hive Drive?

Comment: do you mean the memory settings of the jvm started hive shell ?  These are the current setting : -Xmx2000m -XX:MaxPermSize=128M

Comment: that's what i mean

Comment: `dt` is an integer value, why are you searching it as a string?? maybe the `GC` memory is because it takes a long time to search by the data. How long spend this query until it responds to you?

Comment: I guess that could be the reason, it spends so much time querying the data and it just show you the error before show you 0 data found it